# Is AOP confined to session and access validation?

Tags: java, aop

I am new to AOP, and it seems that it can used as an interceptor for some operations, at some points.

So I wonder if checking for a session (is the user logged in) and authenciation can be done using AOP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, access control is one feature that can be implemented using AOP. In fact, features whose implementation is scattered through the code are good candidates for AOP, and authentication, as well as authorization, are typical examples.

Laddad's [AspectJ in action](http://ramnivas.com/ajia.html) is an excellent resource that includes a chapter on how to implement access control using AspectJ.

In general, one could argue that non-functional requirements are usually good candidates for aspect-oriented programming.

Comment: There is a performance overhead for using AOP. Whether or not this is a problem depends on the language used, the implementation, and the constraints that exist on the resources, so there is no definitive answer here.